# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4273-4279: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf, python-2.x

I want to convert an html page to pdf. For that, I access data from excel and store it in a python dictionary. After that I format the string like below.

Write python variables data into file:

```
 html_file.write( html_rcc_string%(row["B_6.2OwnerName"],
                           row["B_6.3OwnerNameH"],))
```

In the above code `html_rcc_string` contains html code, i.e.

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Owner name</td>
        <td>Owner name in hindi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>%s</td>
         <td>%s</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I supply a dictionary variable which has a name in Hindi, it returns the below error.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4273-4279: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I googled for this but I did not find anything. How can I display user name in Hindi? Any suggestions?

Comment: have you looked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339386/python-pyparsing-unicode-characters

Comment: Thankyou..But iam able to print the hindiname in console.When i write hindiname in html_file problem will occur

Comment: @vinaykallepalli Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write unicode strings into a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483423/how-to-write-unicode-strings-into-a-file)

Comment: @senshin, have you tried any of those answers?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, why?

Comment: @senshin, nvm forgot a u'.

Comment: Have you had a look at the 100 **Related** answers and questions on the right side? I think you are able to build a solution by looking at what they have in common.

Comment: thanks for response, but answers in  How to write unicode strings into a file?  not working for me when i try to call directly .encode("UTF-8") i got another error i.e  'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: What is the type of `row["B_6.3OwnerNameH"]`. That is, what does this print: `print type(row["B_6.3OwnerNameH"])`?

Comment: type(row["B_6.3OwnerNameH"]) is unicode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this advice from the excellent *[Pragmatic Unicode -or- How Do I Stop the Pain?](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)*: make a "Unicode sandwich - bytes on the outside, unicode on the inside". That is, convert all input to Unicode the instant you read it, and convert all output to utf8 the instant you write it.

Applying that logic to your program, I have this:

```
# coding: utf8
row = {
  "B_6.2OwnerName": u'ABHAY',
  "B_6.3OwnerNameH": u'अभय' }

html_rcc_string = u'''
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Owner name</td>
        <td>Owner name in hindi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>%s</td>
         <td>%s</td>
    </tr>
</table>
'''

with open('/tmp/html_file.html', 'w') as html_file:
    html_file.write( (html_rcc_string%(row["B_6.2OwnerName"],
                                      row["B_6.3OwnerNameH"],)).encode('utf8') )
```

There are other ways to invoke the utf8 encoder, but the point remains: ensure that all of your in-program data is `unicode`, not `str`. At the final moment, and only then, do you convert to utf8-encoded `str`.